# Use for the AWS Free Tier

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, vps

I've just completed a Blog Project in Django. While looking for hosting solutions, I found that running the project on the Shared Hosting offered by majority of the Hosting Providers wasn't possible. Dedicated Hosting/ VPS would be too expensive for a simple  project such as these - A small Blog, a few static websites which probably won't have a lot of traffic etc.

A friend told me about [AWS Free Usage Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) today and after checking it out, I had a few questions:

- Does signing up for this give me a complete VPS over which I have complete control?
- Can I monitor/regulate traffic from a browser-based console so that I don't exceed their bandwidth cap (this is highly unlikely but I'd like to be prepared)
- I understand that this probably isn't production grade material and Amazon's offering this so that we can give it a try. Is this correct?
- OS - I found that they offer a special kind of OS called [AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/amis/). Does this function like a normal OS with all its features (a little confused because I saw different stacks and I don't have a clue what they are). Are these preconfigured or can we customize the?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers:

- Yes - it does
- No, can't cap bandwidth
- No. They are just like any other VM
- AMI stands for 'Amazon Machine Image' - not an OS.  All kinds of OS images are available, including Amazon's own Linux flavour.  On the community tab, you can find Ubuntu, Fedora and many ohers.  Yes, they work exactly like they do on any other VM.  Just pick a new one like Ubuntu 12.10 or 12.04LTS - they have kernels more optimised for virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

Full features of AWS Free Tier is applicable for new users who registers with them. Free Tier has some limitations in using the EC2 Instnaces.

AWS AMIs(Amazon Machine Instances) are nothing but Linux and Windows server Instances.

You will have the complete control of all your virtual cloud server Instance that you create.

-Palaniappan